# How to add an event listener to multiple element IDs

Tags: javascript

Below is my approach to add listener to multiple ids.

```
function onImageClick(event) {
//i am not getting below console msg
  console.log('Event Registered');
}

var queryResult = document.getElementsByClassName('ui-grid-cell');
Array.from(queryResult).forEach(function(element) {
  document.getElementById(element.id).addEventListener("click",onImageClick);
});
```

Above approach is not working for me. what mistake i am doing?

Comment: Do those elements have an `id`? And why are you looking for the `id`? You already have the element, just use: `element.addEventListener('click', OnImageClick);`

Comment: What does _"is not working"_ mean?

Answer (score 1):

This approach should work :

```
var queryResult = document.getElementsByClassName('ui-grid-cell');
Array.from(queryResult).forEach(function(element) {
    element.addEventListener("click",onImageClick);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

this will works

```js
 function onImageClick(event) {
          alert('Event Registered');
        }
        
        var queryResult = document.getElementsByClassName('ui-grid-cell');
        
        for(var i=0;i<queryResult.length;i++){
        if(queryResult[i].id && queryResult[i].id !=""){
            document.getElementById(queryResult[i].id).addEventListener("click",onImageClick);
        }
        }
```

```css
img{
margin:15px;
padding:10px;
border-radius:10px;
box-shadow:1px 1px 1px #ccc;
}
```

```html
<img title='this should listen' src='https://www.google.com.eg/images/nav_logo242.png' class='ui-grid-cell' id='div1'/>
<img src='https://www.google.com.eg/images/nav_logo242.png' class='ui-grid-cell'/>
<img title='this should listen' src='https://www.google.com.eg/images/nav_logo242.png' class='ui-grid-cell' id='div2'/>
<img src='https://www.google.com.eg/images/nav_logo242.png' class='ui-grid-cell'/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your same code is working fine, perhaps you missed putting id to the image?

```js
function onImageClick(event) {
//i am not getting below console msg
  console.log('Event Registered');
}

var queryResult = document.getElementsByClassName('ui-grid-cell');
Array.from(queryResult).forEach(function(element) {
  document.getElementById(element.id).addEventListener("click",onImageClick);
});
```

```html
<img src="https://dummyimage.com/50x50/000/fff"
     class="ui-grid-cell" id="one">
<img src="https://dummyimage.com/50x50/ccc/fff"
class="ui-grid-cell" id="two">
<img src="https://dummyimage.com/50x50/123456/fff"
class="ui-grid-cell" id="three">
```

Answer (score -2):

If you use JQuery just use this

```
$(".ui-grid-cell").click(function(){

});
```

Comment: He's clearly not using jQuery, since there's none in the question and nor is it featured in the question tags. Also, jQuery is in no way necessary to solve this problem.

Comment: But I do not want to use jquery.

Comment: Maybe for others  might be useful , this is not about fight is about helping people

Comment: @DavidThomas 
you are correct.I want a solution with jquery.